# Understanding this SQL LEFT JOIN (with IS NULL) example

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, adjacency-list

In a database, there is a table called category:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
        category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        parent INT DEFAULT NULL
);
```

It was created to make an Adjacent List Model Tree. Here is what is inside the table currently:

[image]

In this example (you can find the source link at the bottom), the following sql code was used to obtain of the "leaf" elements in the table, with "leaf" elements being the rows in the table that did not have any other row use their "category_id" in the "parent" column. The following code was run:

```
SELECT t1.name FROM
category AS t1 LEFT JOIN category as t2
ON t1.category_id = t2.parent
WHERE t2.category_id IS NULL;
```

The result of the previous SQL code gives this result:

[image]

For example, there is no row in the table that has the value 3 inside the parent column, hence TUBE (with category_id == 3) is a "leaf" element.

**QUESTION:** Why did that sql code logically give this result? I'm happy that it does since it is what I needed, but I can't wrap my head around the reasoning behind it.

---

source of the example: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: `Outer joins` with `null` checks are a common pattern to see if a record exists in a table, in this case checking if the `category_id` is a `parent` .   Very similar to using `not exists` or `not in`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you see this pattern:

```
SELECT    ...
FROM      TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.column = TableB.column
WHERE     TableB.id is null
```

Think: "find rows in TableA that do not exist in TableB`.

Your query means "find categories that have no child". It's easier to understand if you remove the `WHERE` clause and add a few more columns to the query:

```
SELECT      t1.category_id,
            t1.name,
            t2.name  AS ChildName
FROM        category AS t1
LEFT JOIN   category as t2 ON t1.category_id = t2.parent
```

Here's what happens in your query:

1. Start with the `category` table, alias it as `t1` and `t2`. I'll refer to the aliases from now on.
2. For each row in `t1`, find all records in `t2` that identifies that `t1` row as their parent
3. If a `t1` row has no child, `t2.category_id` will be null
4. We want to filter only for `t1` rows that have no child

Comment: Ok so I am getting really close to understanding! line 1 perfect, line 2 perfect, line 3 **If a t1 row has no child, t2.category_id will be null** is where I'm confused. Don't all of the cells in column t2.category_id have values in it from the start?

Comment: Think "if I can't find any child for you, I will leave `null` in place of your child's `category_id`"

Comment: So would this reasoning be correct?: The `FROM
category AS t1 LEFT JOIN category as t2
ON t1.category_id = t2.parent` first lists all of t1's info, and adds only the info of the MATCHING t2 columns. Since some t1.category_id don't match with any t2.parent, they will have NULL values for both t2.parent AND t2.category_id. From there, code says: `WHERE t2.category_id IS NULL` (I only want the ones that didn't match) and only want the names column `SELECT t1.name`? Would that also mean that I could replace `WHERE t2.category_id IS NULL;` with `WHERE t2.parent_id IS NULL;` and get the same result?

Comment: Yes, you are right in both cases. Your description is rather technical though

Comment: you my dear friend deserve a genius badge from stackoverflow if you don't already have one

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to see what is happening if you rename your table alias:

```
    SELECT tparent.name 
      FROM category AS tparent 
      LEFT JOIN category as tchild
        ON tparent.category_id = tchild.parent
     WHERE tchild.category_id IS NULL;
```

Now it might be easier to see what you are asking for is a list of all the parent category names that have no children [tchild.category_id IS NULL]